# Spring Boot + JPA: "Unable to locate Attribute with the given name" in a derived class

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on an application that uses Spring Boot + JPA to save some entities. However these entities (and the Spring configuration of course) are the only thing in the application that depend on Spring/JPA. That's why we wanted to split the application into two components. The core application  that's supposed to be independent of Spring and any JPA related things and the Spring application. For this purpose we created an interface and a base implementation of the entity in the core application and a derived implementation in the Spring application that only overrides the getters and uses property access. But now Spring complains that the fields are not present.

Here is the class in the core application, basically just a bunch of getters and setters:

```
public class UserImpl implements User {

protected Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<>();

protected Set<Playlist> playlists = new HashSet<>();

protected String userName;
protected String password;
protected String securityQuestion;
protected String securityQuestionAnswer;
protected String token;

public UserImpl() {
}

public UserImpl(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getSecurityQuestion() {
    return securityQuestion;
}

public void setSecurityQuestion(String securityQuestion) {
    this.securityQuestion = securityQuestion;
}

public String getSecurityQuestionAnswer() {
    return securityQuestionAnswer;
}

public void setSecurityQuestionAnswer(String securityQuestionAnswer) {
    this.securityQuestionAnswer = securityQuestionAnswer;
}

public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
    this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
}

public List<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
    return new ArrayList<>(userProfiles);
}

public void setToken(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

public String getToken() {
    return token;
}

public void setPlaylists(Set<Playlist> playlists) {
    this.playlists = playlists;
}

public Set<Playlist> getPlaylists() {
    return playlists;
}

}
```

And here is the derived class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "users", schema = "musictinder")
public class JPAUserImpl extends UserImpl {

@Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
@Column(name = "user_name")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public String getUserName() {
    return super.getUserName();
}

@Override
@Column(name = "password")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public String getPassword() {
    return super.getPassword();
}

@Override
@Column(name = "security_question")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public String getSecurityQuestion() {
    return super.getSecurityQuestion();
}

@Override
@Column(name = "security_question_answer")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public String getSecurityQuestionAnswer() {
    return super.getSecurityQuestionAnswer();
}

@Override
@Column(name = "token")
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public String getToken() {
    return super.getToken();
}

@Override
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public Set<Playlist> getPlaylists() {
    return super.getPlaylists();
}

@Override
@ElementCollection
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
public List<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
    return super.getUserProfiles();
}
}
```

**Update:**
I discovered that Spring only complains about the `userName` field. When I add it to the derived class the application doesn't crash. For some reason it just works with the other fields. Now I am actually more confused than before.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the @MappedSuperclass annotation on your super class `UserImpl`

See docs https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

Comment: Nope, that didn't help. It must be a pretty weird issue, see my update.